# CSS: Resize Element rather than clear the float

Tags: html, css

I have a box which contains an image, which has float:left set, and textual contents.

```
-------------------------------------
|---------                           |
||       |                           | 
|| Image |                           |
||       |       Content             |
|---------                           |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
--------------------------------------
                                Fig. 1
```

I generally consider it good to have the content float around the image. However, in case of using lists, the following look is annoying:

```
-------------------------------------
|---------                           |
||       |   List                    | 
|| Image |                           |
||       |   1. Item                 |
|---------   2. Item                 |
|  3. Item                           |
|  4. Item                           |
|                                    |
--------------------------------------
                                Fig. 2
```

I'd rather have it the following way (at least for considerably short lists, let's assume the list is short for now)

```
-------------------------------------
|---------                           |
||       |   List                    | 
|| Image |                           |
||       |   1. Item                 |
|---------   2. Item                 |
|            3. Item                 |
|            4. Item                 |
|                                    |
| Additional content (not in list)   |
--------------------------------------
                                Fig. 3
```

I got the above look by making the list `display: inline-block` (and either inserting a `<br>` before the list, or wrapping it in a block-level element)

However, in case of any long list items (longer than the small width of the content field),
the float is cleared.

```
-------------------------------------
|---------                           |
||       |                           | 
|| Image |                           |
||       |                           |
|---------                           |
| 1. Item                            |
| 2. A very long item, which makes   |
|    the list box just as wide as the|
|    outer box.                      |
| 3. More items                      |
-------------------------------------|
                                Fig. 4
```

Why this happens seems clear to me. In the floated environment, first, the list is rendered as a block (because of `display: inline-block`), using the width of the outer box as environment width. As there is a long items, the resulting block will be as wide as the outer box. In a second step, the block is tried to fit next to the floating image, where it won't fit. Lastly, the float is cleared.

Is there any way to amend the situation? Like, first try to render the list with the shorter width, and if that fails, re-render? Or a completely different way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Wouldn't `max-width` on the list do it?

Comment: @bfavaretto: No, the list should take up the whole space if the float is already cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a plain `overflow:hidden` on your list - this should do the trick.

See the **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/e4Dky/)**.

Comment: I don't think it does. Or I misunderstood, at least can't get it to work - please explain why it should.

Comment: Fantastic! It works magically (also with `overflow:auto` and `overflow:scroll`) (hint if the jsfiddle is already gone: don't use inline-block on the list as well!). Where's the relevant portion of the spec that makes this work?

Comment: @JoSo the problem with `auto` is that the browsers may render scrollbars if there's to much content. Take a look in here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#Calculating

Answer (score 3):

Put the list inside a `DIV` that is also floated left with a defined width.

Comment: just what I was going to say. (or `float:right` depending on the plan for the parent)

Comment: That's just like taking the state from Fig. 4, and adding a defined width to the list (which is set to inline-block), isn't it? But I can't bear fixing the width of the list. The list should take up the whole width in case of the float already being cleared.

Comment: @JoSo Considering your comments, I'm not sure if you should use floats at all, then. Did you try making everything inline-block, instead of floating? Just beware of whitespace...

Comment: @bfavaretto I generally have to place more than only one "line" after the image, that's why making the image inline-block won't work.